# My Drupal site uses approx 30mb per page (node & user profiles) load. Acceptable or not?

Tags: performance, drupal

I am using drupal and my website uses approx 30mb per page load for nodes and user profiles. My website has round about 150 contributed modules in addition to a few core optional modules. But most of them are small and installed to improve user experience.

My php memory limit is 128mb.

Is 30mb per page acceptable?? And how many page loads can be handled by it easily in 128mb??

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, at 30MB your app is just sipping on memory. The PHP memory limits are set pretty low.

As far as how many "page loads can be handled by 128MB" of memory, well, that's not really valid. When a request comes in, Apache (or whatever server you're using) hands the request to mod_php or FCGI and your PHP code is interpreted, compiled, run, and then quit. The "application" doesn't act like a daemon waiting for requests to come in, so the memory it consumes is used for the duration of the request and then it gets released for use by other requests/processes.

That 128MB limit is *per request*. That means that so long as you have enough memory (and Apache child processes, etc) you can handle additional requests. If you want to see how your application performs under load, check out [apachebench](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. So, what if 10 users open any page simultaneously? Then my website uses 30 x 10 = 300mb???? I am asking about this statement actually: "so the memory it consumes is used for the duration of the request and then it gets released for use by other requests/processes."

Comment: Essentially yes. There are intricacies like process scheduling that come into play, but for your purposes it's safe to say that to handle 10 simultaneous requests you want 10+ Apache workers/children and at least 300MB of available memory. Note that most requests get handled relatively quickly in PHP, so you could probably handle 5+ requests/s on a single Apache worker/child, one after the other.

Comment: Okay. Does it mean that if users open pages with a time gap of a few seconds like 1 or 2 secs. Then that 300MB can handle quite more than 10 page requests??? like 50+ pages?

Comment: I think the best way for you to understand how many requests in how fast a period of time your app can handle would be to give apachebench a shot. It's not too difficult to learn the basics with in a few minutes, and it's pretty revealing.

Comment: Yeah! I think so! However, thanks a lot for help! You're great!